# Elixir - use module as variable

Tags: elixir

I'm executing a certain function

```
MyModule.function()
```

is there any way to use a function like this:

```
a = MyModule
a.function()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
a = MyModule
a.function()
```